# Display 'Ratings' like stars as per calculated value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have function that returns an array of numbers. Next I have to display same number of stars in the related result id. As a complete noob in JavaScript(still struggling with validations:P ) I tried many things to no avail.
Hopefully the code snippets(current state) below will clear my issue -

```
function display(name1, number1, sign1, name2, number2, sign2, check, y_nat, o_nat) {
    document.getElementById("yname").innerHTML = name1 ;
    document.getElementById("ynumber").innerHTML = number1 ;
    document.getElementById("ysign").innerHTML = sign1 ;
    document.getElementById("oname").innerHTML = name2 ;
    document.getElementById("onumber").innerHTML = number2 ;
    document.getElementById("osign").innerHTML = sign2 ;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = check + '%';
/* I am trying to display y_nat[0] Stars in the result id - yr  by calling a show_image(id, number) function! */
    x = "yr";
    document.getElementById("yr").innerHTML = show_image(x ,y_nat[0]) ;
    x = "yl";
    document.getElementById("yl").innerHTML = y_nat[1] ;
    x = "yf";
    document.getElementById("yf").innerHTML = y_nat[2] ;
    x = "yp";
    document.getElementById("yp").innerHTML = y_nat[3] ;
    x = "ys";
    document.getElementById("ys").innerHTML = y_nat[4] ;
    x = "yi";
    document.getElementById("yi").innerHTML = y_nat[5] ;
    x = "or";
    document.getElementById("or").innerHTML = o_nat[0] ;
    x = "ol";
    document.getElementById("ol").innerHTML = o_nat[1] ;
    x = "of";
    document.getElementById("of").innerHTML = o_nat[2] ;
    x = "op";
    document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = o_nat[3] ;
    x = "os";
    document.getElementById("os").innerHTML = o_nat[4] ;
    x = "oi";
    document.getElementById("oi").innerHTML = o_nat[5] ;
}

function show_image (id,number) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "stars2.png";
        x = number;
    y = id;
        for (i =0; i<x; i++){
        document.getElementById(y).appendChild(img);
    }
}//or something of this sort
```

Please let me know if the issue is unclear. I am still trying to solve it and will be really obliged someone can guide in this. I am trying to learn JavaScript. I am trying to use the code from the following link.
http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-94715.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you execute your script? Are you sure that y_nat[0] returns a valid number? How do you call your "display" function? Are you sure it is even executed? Are you sure "stars2.png" is in the same folder as your html-file? (just some ideas of what could be wrong). Please give some more details.

Comment: @Preli: Yup y_nat[0] returns a valid number which I am able to display. This code is not running but if I use document.getElementById("yl").innerHTML = y_nat[1] ;etc. it will display the number in the id. stars2.png is there in the same folder. Display function is being called from a compute() function which is called on a form submit. Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st problem I see is that you need to have the following two lines IN the loop

```
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "stars2.png";
```

like this:

```
for (var i =0; i<x; i++){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "stars2.png";
    document.getElementById(y).appendChild(img);
}
```

2nd problem: show_image doesn't return anything (except for undefined) but you use it to set the html-content of the element you just added the images:

```
document.getElementById("yr").innerHTML = show_image(x ,y_nat[0]) ;
```

change this line to:

```
show_image(x ,y_nat[0]) ;
```

It could be that there are more things wrong, but that's what I noticed. I made a small example for you that works (tested in IE and Chrome):

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function display() {
    var x = "yr";
    show_image(x ,3) ;
}

function show_image (id,number) {
    var x = number;
    var y = id;
    for (var i =0; i<x; i++){
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "stars2.png";
        document.getElementById(y).appendChild(img);
    }
}


</script>

</head>


<body onload="display();">

<div id="yr"></div>

</body>


</html>
```